# Cell alignment in python-docx

Tags: python-3.x, docx, python-docx, alignment

Я использую библиотеку `docx`.
Мне нужно изменить свойство `alignment` в ячейках таблицы в конкретной строке.
Я делаю это так:

```
currentRow = table.rows[rowIndex]
cells = currentRow.cells
for cell in cells:
    cell.paragraphs[0].alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736364/docx-center-text-in-table-cells
    # Изменение цвета этих ячеек работает.
    shading_elm_1 = parse_xml(r'<w:shd {} w:fill="878787"/>'.format(nsdecls('w')))
    cell._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().append(shading_elm_1)
```

Это не работает.
Я пробовал все значения из `WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT`, но в самой таблице ничего не менялось.
 При выводе значения свойства `alignment` в консоле, получаем что оно действительно меняется. 
Не понятно, почему это никак не влияет на внешний вид ячеек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, мой вопрос некорректен.
Если вы работаете с ячейками таблицы, то сначала задавайте им `text`, а только потом меняется свойство `alignment`. Думаю когда мы делаем наоборот, то присваивание текста ячейки сбивает `alignment`.

```
cell.text = "yourText"
cell.paragraphs[0].alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
```